# Table with vertical and horizontal scrolling and fixed header, scrollview doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to make a table with vertical and horizontal scrolling and fixed header. Layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Horizontal scrolling works well, but the vertical does not scroll to the bottom. What's wrong? Thanks.